# Iterate over Key-Value-Pairs in Windows Batch

Tags: windows, dictionary, batch-file, cmd, key-value

I have a list of Key-Value-Pairs representing setting-names and their value.

```
ssl=strict 
always_use_https=on
minify={"css":"off","html":"off","js":"off"}
key=value
many=more
```

I want to apply each value at the specified setting (key) with a curl request within a batch file:

```
curl -X PATCH "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/%zone%/settings/%key%" ^
    -H "X-Auth-Email: %email%" ^
    -H "X-Auth-Key: %auth%" ^
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
    --data "{\"value\":\"%value%\"}" ^
    --insecure
```

The problem I encountered is the saving of these k-v-pairs and the iteration through them so I send a request for every pair. I can't seem to figure out how to create a dictionary in batch.

If you think there is a different tool than batch better suited for this kind of task, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving the environment variables with their values can be done using:

```
set "SettingsFile=%TEMP%\%~n0.txt"
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
(
    echo ssl=!ssl!
    echo always_use_https=!always_use_https!
    echo minify=!minify!
    echo key=!key!
    echo many=!many!
) >"%SettingsFile%"
endlocal
```

Use for `SettingsFile` whatever you want, but the directory tree must exist.

A single command line in batch file is enough to read them back from file to environment variables:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%SettingsFile%") do set "%%I"
```

That's it. [Delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) should not be enabled on reading back the environment variable names and their values from the settings file for correct reading values with one or more exclamation marks.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).